# Catkin_Ws or Root

Tags: ros, catkin, root

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello dear Users

I have a Catkin Workspace. I have installed a package called Universal_Robot. After installing it i wanted to modify the launch files so when i launch it and when the robot spawns into Gazebo it should load up the world i have created with the model builder in Gazebo. The problem is that the files i have modified are saved in the root, /opt/ros/indigo/share/...ur10.launch for example. Is it possible to do the same modification but not on the root, however in the Catkin_Ws!

Thnank you very much!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/207449/catkin_ws-or-root/) by [DonnY](https://answers.ros.org/users/21798/donny/) on ROS Answers with karma: 55 on 2015-04-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In that case, you have to install the package in your catkin workspace (Catkin_Ws).You can download the source code and build the package in your catkin workspace and then modify the launch files which you want.

---

Originally posted by [Naman](https://answers.ros.org/users/11186/naman/) with karma: 1464 on 2015-04-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2